# Why do Windows Updates kill self-signed SSL certificates?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ssl, ssl-certificate

It seems that every time Windows auto-installs security updates, all of our secure sites return "connection was reset..." messages. After I remove and reapply new self-signed SSL certificates, the sites are back up and running. All of our sites with Verisign or Network Solutions certs are never affected by these updates.

2 questions:

1. Does anyone know why this happens?
2. Is it possible to avoid this issue, without requiring the purchase of trusted certs?

Comment: If it helps, our certificates are generated using SelfSSL

Comment: What do you mean by "remove and reapply new self-signed SSL certificates"? Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: Remove the old certificate through IIS, then run SelfSSL to generate and apply a new cert to the site.  Once I do that, the site is back up and running.

Comment: If you scroll down to "Pawel"s comment on this stackoverflow question, you can see that he mentions this exact scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124392/connection-interrupted-the-connection-to-the-server-was-reset-while-the-page-was

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting in IE to download new certificate authority lists. It's possible that any custom authorities are deleted when the list is updated.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this.  Since this is a web server, I am not concerned with having the most up-to-date certificate authority list.